# Missing required parameter for [Route: password.reset] [URI: reset-password/{token}]

Tags: laravel, authentication, fortify

Im trying to implement the fortify authentication.
When I want to reset the password it opens the route: reset-password. When I open the link it gives me an error message:

Missing required parameter for [Route: password.reset] [URI: reset-password/{token}]

i'm using the following versions:
php 8.0.2
Laravel Framework 8.32.1
npm 6.17.11

Anyone able to help me out with this ?

FortifyServiceProvider.php:

```
        Fortify::loginView(function(){
            return view( view: 'auth.login');
        });

        Fortify::registerView(function(){
            return view( view: 'auth.register');
        });

        Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function(){
            return view( view: 'auth.forgot-password');
        });  
        
        Fortify::resetPasswordView(function($request){
            return view('auth.reset-password', ['token' => $request]);
        });
```

reset-password.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card login-card">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="/img/login.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="brand-wrapper">
                            <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                        </div>
                        <p class="login-card-description">Reset password</p>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.reset') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{$request->route('token')}}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email address" value="{{request->email}}">
                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password">
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Confirm password">
                            </div>
                            <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="submit" value="Update">
                        </form>
                        <p class="login-card-footer-text">Don't have an account? <a href="{{ route('register') }}"
                                class="text-reset">Register here</a></p>
                        <nav class="login-card-footer-nav">
                            <a href="#!">Terms of use.</a>
                            <a href="#!">Privacy policy</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

forgot-password.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card login-card">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="/img/login.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="brand-wrapper">
                            <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                        </div>
                        <p class="login-card-description">Reset password</p>
                        @if(session('status'))
                            {{session('status')}}
                        @endif
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email address">
                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="submit" value="Reset">
                        </form>
                        <p class="login-card-footer-text">Don't have an account? <a href="{{ route('register') }}"
                                class="text-reset">Register here</a></p>
                        <nav class="login-card-footer-nav">
                            <a href="#!">Terms of use.</a>
                            <a href="#!">Privacy policy</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card login-card">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="/img/login.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="brand-wrapper">
                            <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                        </div>
                        <p class="login-card-description">Register a new account</p>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name">

                            </div>
                            @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password">
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Confirm password">
                            </div>
                            <input name="register" id="register" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="submit" value="Register">
                        </form>
                        <a href="#!" class="forgot-password-link">Forgot password?</a>
                        <p class="login-card-footer-text">Alredy have an account? <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-reset">Login here</a></p>
                        <nav class="login-card-footer-nav">
                            <a href="#!">Terms of use.</a>
                            <a href="#!">Privacy policy</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card login-card">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="/img/login.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @if($errors->any())
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="brand-wrapper">
                            <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                        </div>
                        <p class="login-card-description">Sign into your account</p>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="***********">
                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="submit" value="Login">
                        </form>
                        <a href="#!" class="forgot-password-link">Forgot password?</a>
                        <p class="login-card-footer-text">Don't have an account? <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="text-reset">Register here</a></p>
                        <nav class="login-card-footer-nav">
                            <a href="#!">Terms of use.</a>
                            <a href="#!">Privacy policy</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

template.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <main class="d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100 py-3 py-md-0">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is your link look like? Seema like it has missing `?token=`

Comment: /reset-password/c716b5db5c1e5aae5c380355cc1df82cfc822bad62c523ae27c2a0940d9d230d?email=***********

Comment: try: `{{ route('password.reset', ['token'=>request('token')]) }}`

Comment: Hi Martin,

the error about the token is gone. but got a new error back:

Undefined constant "request" (View: /var/www/fortify.evadere.nl/resources/views/auth/reset-password.blade.php)


<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="{{request->email}}">

Comment: without the adjustment of Martin I already saw the following Route parameters token:
832598e11a21685d210d9b46d2d67a2b51da0936eb6949876075f7a6b2cc822e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `reset-password.blade.php` change the `route password.reset` to `password. update` like below

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
```

and this

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email address" value="{{request->email}}">
```

to this

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email address" value="{{$request->email}}">
```

you were missing the `$` in `request->email`

change this `['token' => $request]` to `['request' => $request]` like below

```
 Fortify::resetPasswordView(function($request){
            return view('auth.reset-password', ['token' => $request]);
        });
```

Hope it works

Comment: I adjusted these code changes and that solved it! Most of them just stupid typo's. The last one, I tried what was happening if I would change the request to token.